# Tabulator 4.0 PDF Download formating question

Tags: tabulator

I am trying to change the page size on pdf to ledger when downloading. It is staying the same See code below

```
//trigger download of data.pdf file
    $("#download-pdf").click(function(){
      dsDetails.download("pdf", "data.pdf", {
        orientation:"landscape", //set page orientation to landscape
        units:"mm",
        format:"279,432",
        title:"Opportunity Details", //add title to report
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

the ***units*** and ***format*** options you are using are not valid download parameters for the PDF downloader, the only available properties are ***orientation***, ***title*** and ***autoTable***.

The ***autoTable*** property can take any of the standard auto table options, which can be found on their git repo: https://github.com/simonbengtsson/jsPDF-AutoTable#options

At the moment it is not possible to set any jsPDF options through the params, but this will be coming in the next release

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent some time trying to make this work lol. Great job on the overall tool btw

Comment: Hi Oli, has it come in next release? because I really need to fix [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nd1nz.png). I still cannot set width of page or make the page grow as much it need space to fit columns correctly.

Comment: https://tabulator.info/docs/5.5/download#pdf have a look at the jsPDF option